# Styles and scripts not loading properly. Why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, templates, blogger

I recently found this Blogger template (http://portify-codytemplate.blogspot.in) and the first few times I accessed it, I swear it was still working properly. The styles are just in place and it's just the best template I've found so far. Now, I have uploaded it as my Blogger template. A day later, I accessed it to edit some codes and now it looks so terrible. Is it just me, or are you also seeing the same thing? See photos below:

[image]
[image]

As I looked up the original template (http://portify-codytemplate.blogspot.in), it also looks as horrible. I also have browsed some templates similar to Portify (I got related templates from the site where I got Portify) and they also have the same problem.

I tried accessing these templates in different browsers and machines. They all have the same output. I also looked up the jQuery library in the original code which says:

```
<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js' type='text/javascript'/>
```

Thought it might be outdated so I replaced it with the newer version:

```
<script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js' type='text/javascript'/>
```

But still it didn't work. Nothing happened. 
I would just want to know why are the styles and scripts are not loading properly in this site. PLEASE HELP. Anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem appears to be related to "http://host1.base.pk/".

[image]
[image]

It performs a check and returns HTML before returning the actual CSS or JS. The browser pukes when it sees an HTML response for the external resources.

You can *fix* the problem by visiting a file on the host directly and letting it do it's check:
`http://host1.base.pk/css/prettyPhoto.css`

Once you visit that you should be able to load the rest of the theme easily.

However, I would recommend hosting the external resources someplace you can trust to serve up the content reliably.

Comment: It's NOW working when I visited http://host1.base.pk/css/prettyPhoto.css. Why is that? Sorry but I don't quite understand how that happened. And how do I host in Blogger? Thank you so much.

Comment: I am really wondering why it worked the first few times I accessed the template then it suddenly got terrible.

Comment: After `host1.base.pk` they set a cookie on your machine. The cookie's name is `__test` and it appears to contain some sort of encrypted value. It would appear that the host checks for this cookie before serving content up. 
I would guess that you somehow lost that `__test` cookie as well as your cached resources. (Maybe a different machine, maybe incognito mode?). That would explain why the site looked weird all of a sudden. OR maybe the host decided to implement this cookie recently. I don't really know why they are doing this. But either way that's the reason it's not showing up correctly.

Comment: > *And how do I host in Blogger?*
I'm not entirely sure, I don't typically use Blogger. You might try reading this post, it might help you:
http://www.mybloggerlab.com/2013/04/how-to-host-css-or-javascript-files-in-blogger-using-google-drive.html

You could also try asking another SO question regarding that. (Assuming one doesn't already exist for the subject).

Comment: you're my savior! thank you so much! will keep those information in mind (tho I don't fully understand them but I know I will eventually haha) :)

Comment: I have another question. Do other would also see the same thing (terrible layout) before visiting `http://host1.base.pk/css/prettyPhoto.css`?

Comment: Hi @kaynewilder. I believe so. When I visited http://portify-codytemplate.blogspot.in/ I saw the broken theme. 

You *might* consider contacting whomever made the theme and letting them know of the issue. I don't know if they can fix it on their end.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not the jquery version. the latest jquery version isn't supported in Internet Explorer 6, 7, or 8 I believe.

I suggest to include all the js at the bottom of your script, after you initialized jquery.

so after this line:

```
<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js' type='text/javascript'/>
```

I say this because I see scripts in your body, head and footer. You can see in the element inspector that some functions doesn't work the way they should, high changes that it is because of the order you load scripts. So order them at the bottom of the script and see if you fixed the errors.

Comment: hello! thank you so much for your response. just done doing what you said but unfortunately I still get the same problem. I wasn't able to include in the problem but I also got this error message in the console: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized)`

Comment: I am really wondering why it worked the first few times I accessed the template then it suddenly got terrible.